# Application not returning API request results, but I am unsure where the problem is?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, api

I am creating a basic app that

1. Takes user input via html
2. Forwards it to a PHP routine via ajax in javascript
3. Makes an API request from the PHP routine
4. Return the results of the API request to the front end.
5. Parsse the results using javascript
6. Displays the results in html

I am running it using apache and am not getting any results returned for the astergdem section, however it does work for the country info section, but I can not find the problem anywhere, here is my:

html:

```
    <select id="selCountry">
        <option value="GB">Great Britain</option>
        <option value="FR">France</option>
        <option value="DE">Germany</option>
        <option value="US">USA</option>
    </select>

    <select id="selLanguage">
        <option value="en">English</option>
        <option value="fr">Francais</option>
        <option value="de">Deutsche</option>
    </select>

    <button id="btnRun">Run</button>

    <br><br>

    <div id="divResults">
        
        <table>

            <tr>
                <td align="right">
                    Continent: 
                </td>
                <td id="txtContinent">
                    
                </td>

            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td align="right">
                    Capital: 
                </td>
                <td id="txtCapital">
                    
                </td>

            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td align="right">
                    Languages: 
                </td>
                <td id="txtLanguages">
                    
                </td>

            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td align="right">
                    Population: 
                </td>
                <td id="txtPopulation">
                    
                </td>

            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td align="right">
                    Area (km<sup>2</sup>): 
                </td>
                <td id="txtArea">
                    
                </td>

            </tr>


        </table>

    </div>
    <div id="inputContainer">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>API name</td>
                <td>API description</td>
                <td>submit</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Astergem</td>
                <td>Returns a single number giving the elevation in meters according to aster gdem<br>
                    Latitude:
                    <input id="latitude" name="latitude" type="number" value="50.01"><br>
                    Longitude:
                    <input id="longitude" name="longitude" type="number" value="10.2" >


                </td>
                <td><button id="asterBtn">submit</button></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>

    <div id="divResultsAstergem">
        
        <table>

            <tr>
                <td align="right">
                    Longitude: 
                </td>
                <td id="txtLng">
                    
                </td>

            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td align="right">
                    Latitude: 
                </td>
                <td id="txtLat">
                    
                </td>

            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td align="right">
                    Elevation: 
                </td>
                <td id="txtAster">
                    
                </td>

            </tr>



        </table>

    </div>

    <script type="application/javascript" src="libs/js/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="application/javascript" src="libs/js/script.js"></script>

</body>
```

javascript:
$('#btnRun').click(function() {

```
    $.ajax({
        url: "libs/php/getCountryInfo.php",
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            country: $('#selCountry').val(),
            lang: $('#selLanguage').val()
        },
        success: function(result) {

            console.log(JSON.stringify(result));

            if (result.status.name == "ok") {

                $('#txtContinent').html(result['data'][0]['continent']);
                $('#txtCapital').html(result['data'][0]['capital']);
                $('#txtLanguages').html(result['data'][0]['languages']);
                $('#txtPopulation').html(result['data'][0]['population']);
                $('#txtArea').html(result['data'][0]['areaInSqKm']);

            }
        
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            // your error code
        }
    }); 

});

$('#asterBtn').click(function() {

    $.ajax({
        url: "libs/php/getAster.php",
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            lat: $('#latitude').val(),
            lng: $('#longitude').val()
        },
        success: function(result) {

            console.log(JSON.stringify(result));

            if (result.status.name == "ok") {

                $('#txtLat').html(result['data'][0]['lat']);
                $('#txtAster').html(result['data'][0]['astergdem']);
                $('#txtLng').html(result['data'][0]['lng']);

            }
        
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            
        }
    }); 

});
```

and php:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$executionStartTime = microtime(true);

$url='http://api.geonames.org/astergdemJSON?formatted=true&lat=' . $_REQUEST['lat'] . '&lng=' . $_REQUEST['lng'] . '&username=lizzyknee%0A&style=full';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);

$result=curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);

$decode = json_decode($result,true);    

$output['status']['code'] = "200";
$output['status']['name'] = "ok";
$output['status']['description'] = "success";
$output['status']['returnedIn'] = intval((microtime(true) - $executionStartTime) * 1000) . " ms";
$output['data'] = $decode['geonames'];

header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8');

echo json_encode($output);
```

?>
(I have another php file for the country info. it is identical to this barring the URL.)

I have tried to input the longitude and latitude and get the returned astergdem elevation, but go no result.
I am unsure where I have gone wrong as it is working for the first api. I know the html is poor but i just need it to display the results

Edit: nothing is logged to the console when i click the button
Edit: I also have noticed that the array i am trying to decode doesn't actually have a name. it is referred to as 'geonames' on the php here, but I forgot to change that to the name of the array in the JSON file, however when i look at the file the array has no name, and I don't know how to decode that

Comment: `I am unsure where I have gone wrong` - I would start by checking what response you get from the `getAster.php` request by looking in the browser devtools network tab.  You might be getting an error instead of the json response.

Comment: How the output of `console.log(JSON.stringify(result));` within `$('#asterBtn').click(...)` looks? Please add this into the question.

Comment: Thank you, I've just checked this and it doesnt seem to be making the request at all,only the getCountry.php is appearing in the network tab. What would this mean?

Comment: You're sending your username with an encoded linefeed character at the end of it -- probably not what you want: `&username=lizzyknee%0A&style=full`

Comment: the console.log within the $('#asterBtn').click doesnt actually work, nothing is getting logged to the console. Ive also tried changing the username part of the url but i dont think thats the problem as it works fine for the first api url

Comment: you have mismatch in json format, either just drop `dataType: 'json',` or add `data: JSON.stringify({ .. }),` and `$_REQUEST = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));` also add "error reporting code" to the ajax error callback function like: `error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { console.log('Error status: ' + textStatus + ', error thrown: ' + errorThrown + ', response text: ' + jqXHR.responseText); }` so you know whats going on

Comment: The `console.log()` happens in the success callback, but does the request happen at all?  Check the network tab of developer tools.  If it happens, what is the server response? Anything in your web server or PHP logs?